# Check if an object from image is or isn't a character

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr

I made a character extractor from images, more exactly adapted for images that have subtitles. I made threshold on image and I extracted all individual objects from it. Now, between objects are characters and I have to recognize only them, not other objects that aren't characters. I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CK0OCeCN9zg) on the internet and I tested it. It uses KNN recognition, but the problem is that it finds all objects in every image tested characters, even if they are not(because it finds nearest match on characters from the vocabulary). Does anyone knows if I can modify the program such that to have like a percentage of match and if it doesn't, to return nothing? Any help is welcome. You can find the code for the program [here](https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/OpenCV_3_KNN_Character_Recognition_Cpp).

Comment: What do the extracted results look like? Maybe you could do cross-correlation on a database of known-good characters; that shouldn't be too slow.

Comment: [photo of the results](http://imgur.com/a/Bf8WE)

Comment: On the bottom is the image cropped in half and thresholded and up are some of the objects detected including characters.